# Node .js server with nginx and basic auth

Tags: node.js, nginx, server, basic-authentication

I'm trying to run a node.js server behind nginx, with a basic auth. Here is my minimal config:

```
server {
  auth_basic "closed website";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://localhost:3000/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

My first problem is that when I go to the x.x.x.x, the basic auth form re-appears every time (indefinitely) I hit enter (whatever I set as login and password - even the good ones).

The server simply returns some plain text `res.end("Hello World\n");`, which I can see for a second before the basic auth form appears again.

Second question, is it possible to block the x.x.x.x:3000 (if not, there is no point in setting an auth on :80).

Thanks!

Btw it's the first time I setup nginx (and i spent quite a lot of time on it already).

Note: it works without a basic auth (or with `auth_basic off;` in my location).

Currently my website looks always like that:
[image]
:)

Answer (score 0):

Ok my bad, got it!

Apparently the passwords in .htpasswd [**have to be encrypted**](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html), `openssl passwd` worked just fine.

The second question was an easy one, `iptables` is there for that.

Hope this might help some other new users of nginx!

Answer (score 0):

I have used your sample succesfully.

You dont need to create the iptables rule if you force node to listen only in localhost.

To create the .passwd file you can use htpasswd too:

```
htpasswd -c path/.passwdfile user
```

If missing:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-utils
```